# while uploading csv file displays something else in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I was uploading csv file and wanted to display it, but it displays something else. This is the output:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVhVq.png)

*Here's my code*
**Upload.php in Controller**

```
    <?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
  exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
   }

  //if index is loaded
    public function index() {
        //load the helper library
        $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
        //Set the message for the first time
        $data = array('msg' => "Upload File");

    $data['upload_data'] = '';

        //load the view/upload.php with $data
        $this->load->view('upload', $data);


    }


}
```

*Here's my another controller*
**Upload_file.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload_file extends CI_Controller{


  function __construct()
  {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }


    function upload_it() {
        //load the helper
        $this->load->helper('form');

        //Configure
        //set the path where the files uploaded will be copied. NOTE if using linux, set the folder to permission 777
        $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/';

    // set the filter image types
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|csv';

        //load the upload library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

        $data['upload_data'] = '';

        //if not successful, set the error message
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        } else { //else, set the success message
            $data = array('msg' => "Upload success!"); 

      $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();

        }

        //load the view/upload.php
        $this->load->view('upload', $data);

    }

}
```

**EDIT **
*And here's my view*
**upload.php**

```
    <html> 
    <head>
           <!-- <style type="text/css">
            ::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
            ::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
            ::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
            body {
                background-color: #fff;
                margin: 40px;
                font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #4F5155;
            }
            a {
                color: #003399;
                background-color: transparent;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            h1 {
                color: #444;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
                font-size: 19px;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0 0 14px 0;
                padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
            }
            code {
                font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
                font-size: 12px;
                background-color: #f9f9f9;
                border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
                color: #002166;
                display: block;
                margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
                padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
            }
            #body{
                margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
            }
            p.footer{
                text-align: right;
                font-size: 11px;
                border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
                line-height: 32px;
                padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
                margin: 20px 0 0 0;
            }
            #container{
                margin: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
            }-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- <div id="container">
            <h1>How to upload file in Codeigniter</h1>-->
            <div id="body">



<code><?php echo $msg;?></code>


<code>
<?php if($upload_data != ''):?>
<?php var_dump($upload_data);?>

</code>

<?php endif;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('Upload_file/upload_it');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="submit" value="upload" class="btn btn-success" />

</form>



 </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```$this->upload->data();``` shows the file data (attributes), not file content. You have to read the CSV using php and then send it to view. Create proper tabular HTML to show the records.

Comment: Please see Edit. Is it ok now?

Comment: where you are reading CSV??

Comment: once you have uploaded the file, in the upload_file controller, you will need to use something like redirect($data['upload_data']['file_path'], 'refresh') if you want to view the file itself in the browser (this requires url helper to be loaded). If you are wanting the data from the file, that you would then load into the view, you would need to do a file_get_contents($data['upload_data']['file_path']) and pass that to the view

Comment: @ScottMiller : he want to get content from the file, as you suggested ```file_get_contents``` will work for him. May be he thinks that ```$this->upload->data()``` do the same thing, which is wrong.